# Custom ErrorHandler is not working when provided in feature modules (LazyLoading)?

Tags: angular

### **Custom ErrorHandler is not working when provided in feature modules (LazyLoading) !**

It works when my custom ErrorHandler is provided at the time of app bootstrap, but not working when provided in feature modules !! I am using lazy loading and trying to implement multiple custom ErrorHandler specific to feature(lazy) modules. Is that possible ? kindly help..

Comment: You want it to be a custom error handler for just the module where it is provided? I don't think that is possible (but I might be wrong).

Comment: ya.A custom error handler for a particular module.According to angular DI, i expect that to work.!!